# Increase maximum file size for deployment logs in Azure ML Studio?

Tags: azure, deployment, containers, azure-machine-learning-service

I am testing a segmentation model deployed as an endpoint in Azure ML Studio. In the endpoint you can select deployment logs, which are the only means of viewing errors in the active container. I am running into an issue where new lines are not being written to the log, which seems to have maxed out at 5000 lines.

I have had no luck determining if this is due to a max file size or line limit, but even greater to that problem is that I have found now way of deleting the log, so it seems the only way for me to continue is to rebuild the deployment entirely.

I have confirmed that the container is still running as I can get scoring results back.

Any help would be greatly appreciated in either deleting the log or increasing the max size limit

I would have assumed the log would be kept in the storage account for the workspace alongside the build log, but its nowhere to be found.

I have tried querying the log from the cli trailing the last 200 lines and confirmed that it is stuck at 5000 lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable  **Enable Application Insights diagnostics and data collection** option while deploying the endpoint.
which helps you to monitor the logs.

[image]

After deployment, go to resource group, find your endpoint
and click on it. Then you will see the option in left pane **Logs**.

Open that and search for machine learning in search bar under queries tab. Then you will see results as below.
[image]

In that, hover on `Online endpoint console logs` and click on **Run** you will get results as below. There you can see your logs.

[image]

But default in that query it will top 100 records just change it to desired number you need.

[image]

[You refer this documentation for more information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-monitor-online-endpoints?view=azureml-api-2)